# Let $A\in M_{n}(\mathbf{C})$ whose rank is $r$. Let $m_A$ denote its minimal polynomial. Show $\deg m_A\leq r+1$. Find conditions when $\deg m_A=r+1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, proof-explanation

**Problem**: Let $A \in M_{n}(\mathbf{C})$ whose rank is $r$. Let $m_A$ denote its minimal polynomial. Prove $\deg m_A \leq r+1$. Find conditions when $\deg m_A=r+1$.

**Attempt**: We'll Jordanize $ A $, meaning there exists $ P \in M_n{(\mathbf{C})} $ invertible and $ R \in  M_n{(\mathbf{C})}  $ in Jordan form s.t. $ A = P^{-1} R P $. There are at most $ r $ different eigenvalues for $ A $ since rank is preserved under similarity and so the rank of $ A $ in Jordan basis is also $ r $ ( hence there'll be at most $ r $ eigenvalues on the diagonal, not necessarily all different ).
So it occurs that the characteristic polynomial of $ A $ is $ \Delta_A(x) = ( x-\lambda_1) \cdots( x - \lambda_r) $, and the eigenvalues not need all be different.
Denote as $ m_A $ the minimal polynomial of $ A $. We know that $ m_A \mid \Delta_A  $ and thus $ m_A $ is also made up of multiplications of linear terms. We also know that every eigenvalue is a root of $ m_A $.
If all the eigenvalues are different then $ m_A = ( x-\lambda_1) \cdots( x - \lambda_r)  $ and thus $ \deg m_A = r $.
Else, $ \Delta_A(x) = ( x-\lambda_{j_1})^{k_{j_1}} \cdots( x - \lambda_{j_q})^{k_{j_q}} $ where $ q \leq r $ and $ k_{j_i} $ is the algebraic multiplicity of eigenvalue $ \lambda_{j_i} $ and $\forall \alpha \neq \beta. \lambda_{j_\alpha} \neq \lambda_{j_\beta}  $. And thus, $ m_A(x) = ( x-\lambda_{j_1})^{\tau_{j_1}} \cdots( x - \lambda_{j_q})^{\tau_{j_q}} $ where $ \tau_{j_i} \leq k_{j_i} $.
Since $ k_{j_1} + \cdots + k_{j_r} =n $
[Here I've stopped because I noticed $ \tau_{j_1} + \cdots + \tau_{j_r} \leq n $ and **not** necessarily that $ \tau_{j_1} + \cdots + \tau_{j_r} \leq r+1 $ as I've hoped for which would tell me that $ \deg m_A < r+1 $.]

**Official solution:**
We may assume that $A$ is in its Jordan form. Let $\lambda$ denote an eigenvalue for $A$. Let $J_{m}(\lambda)$ denote the largest Jordan block which appears in $A$ and is associated with $\lambda$. In other words, if $J_{k}(\lambda)$ also appears in $A$, then $k \leq m$. Thus, this eigenvalue will contribute a factor of $(t-\lambda)^{m}$ to the minimal polynomial, and hence it will contribute the factor $m$ to the degree of $m(t)$. Notice that the rank of the matrix $J_{m}(\lambda)$ is $m$ if $\lambda \neq 0$ and is equal to $m-1$ if $\lambda=0$. Thus, each eigenvalue $\lambda$ contributes to the degree of $m(t)$ a factor which is less or equal to the number rank $J_{m}(\lambda)+1$, where $J_{m}(\lambda)$ is as above. Summing over all eigenvalues, the result follows.

We'll now find conditions when there is an equality. Assume first that $J_{m}(\lambda)$ is the largest block appearing in $A$ and that $\lambda \neq 0$. Then this is the only Jordan block associated with $\lambda$ which appears in $A$. Indeed, if $J_{k}(\lambda)$ also appears in $A$, then $\lambda$ will contribute a factor of $m$ to the degree of $m(t)$, but at least a factor of $m+k$ to the rank of $A$. Hence there can not be an equality. Therefore, we can have at most one block associated with each nonzero eigenvalue. The only way we can increase the degree of $m(t)$ by a factor which is greater then the contribution to the rank is by having at least one block Jordan of the form $J_{m}(0)$. However, to obtain the equality $\deg m(t)=r+1$ we cannot have more than one Jordan block of the form $J_{m}(0)$ with $m>1$.

To summarize the equality $\deg m(t)=r+1$ holds if and only if $A$ has the following Jordan decomposition
$$
\left(\begin{array}{lllll}
J_{m_{1}}\left(\lambda_{1}\right) & & & & \\
& \ddots & & & \\
& & J_{m_{k}}\left(\lambda_{k}\right) & & \\
& & & J_{m_{k+1}}(0) & & \\
& & & & 0_{l}  
\end{array}\right)
$$
Here $\lambda_{i} \neq \lambda_{j}$ for all $i \neq j$, and for all $1 \leq i \leq k$ we have $\lambda_{i} \neq 0 .$ Also, $m_{k+1} \geq 1$ and $l \geq 0$. By $0_{l}$ we mean the zero matrix of size $l$. For $A$ as above we have $m(t)=t^{m_{k+1}}\left(t-\lambda_{1}\right)^{m_{1}} \dots\left(t-\lambda_{k}\right)^{m_{k}}$ and $\operatorname{rank} A=m_{1}+\cdots+m_{k}+m_{k+1}-1$. So $\deg m(t)=r+1$.

**Note**: The same question appears [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670939), but the OP didn't prove the professor's solution plus I didn't fully understand the provided answer. I took a different approach (one that is similar to that provided in the official solution above.)

**Question:**

1. I feel like I need to relate my attempt to the 'official solution' in order to understand. Is there a way to proceed the proof using what I've done? if so then how? (The things bothering me with the official proof is the part where it's written "Summing over all eigenvalues, the result follows." in the first paragraph - how the result follows? And in the second paragraph where it's written "Hence there can not be an equality." - I still couldn't understand where's the contradiction?) If you've got a clearer proof in the spirit of the above, that'd also be appreciated!
2. In my attempt I've got that $ \deg m_A = r $ which is wrong, but why?

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: "There are at most $r$ different eigenvalues for $A$" is incorrect. For example, consider the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0\\&1\\&&2}.
$$

Comment: Ok, now I'm beginning to understand. The rank of the provided matrix is 2 but there are 3 eigenvalues and 3 Jordan blocks $ ( J_1(0),J_1(1),J_1(2) ) $. I should've thought of a different way to tackle the problem.

Comment: Does this amount to saying "for each non-zero eigenvalue,  its eigenspace has dimension $1$"?

Comment: @Ned I don't see how the above theorem implies what you proposed since for example $\pmatrix{0\\&1\\&&2\\&&&2}$ for $ \lambda = 2 $ its eigenspace has dimension 2 while the rank of the matrix is 4, care to explain please?

Comment: @hazelnut_116 The rank of that matrix is $3$, and the minimum poly $x(x-1)(x-2)$ has degree $3$ so that doesn't satisfy $d=r+1$. But I messed up by leaving out the conditions that [$0$ is an eigenvalue and there's at most one Jordan block of size $2$ or more for the eigenvalue $0$], which is necessary. What I wrote above was equivalent to "only one Jordan block for each non-zero eigenvalue" but that's not enough. In your example, if you insert a $1$ in 3rd row, 4th column to make J-block of size $2$ for eigenvalue $2$, then you'd have rank = $3$ and degree(min poly) = $4$.

Comment: you can simplify this by considering that $ V = \text{image}A^n \oplus \ker A^n $ with $\text{rank}(A^n)=p$ and letting $\mathbf B$ be a basis for $V$ with the first $p$ vectors being a basis for $\text{image}A^n$ and the rest being a basis for $\ker A^n$. Then $A\mathbf B= \mathbf B\begin{bmatrix}
T_p & \mathbf 0\\ 
\mathbf 0 & N_{n-p}
\end{bmatrix}$ where $T$ is invertible and $N$ is nilpotent.  $\text{degree }m_A= \text{degree }m_T + \text{degree }m_N$ where the former has Cayley Hamilton for a bound and the latter has a bound implied by $\text{rank}A^{k+1}\leq \text{rank}A^{k}$